# Misplaced sense of an ASP PlaceHolder control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, placeholder

I have a simple div on html, something like:

```
<div class="warning">
    <h3>Please make sure:</h3>
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="phWarnings" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="$('#warning').hide()">Okay</a>
</div>
```

The PlaceHolder is being populated with a couple of radio buttons, a covering div, some `h4` and `p` elements.

However, when the page shows up, the whole div (along with its children contents) are completely outside the warning div. I thought I was messing up the div structure in codebehind so I just commented out everything and did this:

```
phWarnings.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Meh"));
```

Guess what?  Yeah, the string "Meh" was outside the warning div too. The HTML (on view source) option
shows this:

```
<div class="warning">
    <h3>Please make sure:</h3>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="$('#warning').hide()">Okay</a>
</div>

Meh
```

I have done the similar things other times but never faced this problem. I was hoping you guys could shed some light on why placeholder decided to go out of parent div or how to avoid it. removing the class from warning div etc doesn't seem to work.

Any idea why this is happening please?

Comment: IIRC, a placeholder doesn't render as a div, so you _might_ want some kind of container about the placeholder (a <P> or a <DIV>). Also, is this contained in any other control?

Comment: @David, what is IIRC? Yes I do know the placeholder doesnt add anything extra so I am covering all controls inside a div on codebehind. Also, I tried just a plain string, which behaves in the same way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things don't just happen, they happen for a reason.  If they look as if they just happen, then that just means you don't know the reason... which is why you are asking.  So...

The problem has to be with either your html or your css.  As you don't give us much to go on, there isn't much that anyone can say.

You could put a page up, and provide a link to that, for people to look at the html and the css.  No reason you can't do that.

Things to look out for in your css?  floats that haven't been cleared for example.

Things to look out for in the Html?  Unclosed tags.

You can diagnose the above kind of problem by right clicking on the offending area and doing "Inspect Element" when viewing the page in either Google Chrome or FireFox?

Are you assigning css classes using jquery or similar?  Probably not, given your inline js code in the a tag...

All the above or a combination thereof are possible candidates, but in the absence of a page to look at, your not going to get much help.

Comment: Hi, the reason I cant give out the html is because, as I mentioned, when I inspect from firebug, the warning div closes and then the placeholder starts - plus the placeholder is being populated on codebehind, so I dont know where to put up a page and show the code for c#, but I have given what goes on in c# plus copy pasted the resultant html code. I agree with your ``that just means you don't know the reason`` which is correct.

Comment: after I read your answer, I changed everthing, now I just have ``<div><placeholder...></div>`` but when I compile the string is outside div anyway.

Comment: actually after a lot of debugging, I found out that I was adding controls to wrong placeholder. *Feeling incredibly stupid*. Thanks for the help and pushing me to check for everything.

Comment: Not incredibly stupid, sounds like me on a good day...  Thanks for ticking the answer, but can I suggest that you add the resolution to your problem to your question?  Someone with a similar problem may miss your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be correct but what i interpreted from the description is you are appending some HTML from code behind into your place holder.

If it is possible you can append the elements into your div 
through jquery.

$('div.warning').append("your content")

Comment: Hi, Its possible in a normal scenario via ajax (since I need to check values on the user table in db) but in this case its not very feasible solution. so no.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, are you overriding the page's render method? And ff you try and change the containing div to runat="server" what happens?